# How can one read a text file in a Struts 2 app

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee, configuration, resources

Developing a Struts 2 app I run in a following problem. I need to read a text file that is deployed in web server with my app. How can I access it knowing its relative path. In other words how can I find absolute path if I know relative path inside the deployed directory.
When I had similar problem with servlets I used to use this.getContextPath() (or something similar) that returned an absolute path to the folder in the webserver.

EDIT:
Thank you guys for answer. For me worked this:

```
String path=GetPointsOfInterestAction.class.getResource("../../../resources/visitor_attractions.txt")
```

Could you please explain why I it worked because I'm making first steps in java.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If it is placed in the webapp's classpath, then just use:

```
InputStream input = servletContext.getResourceAsStream("file.txt");
```

If it is placed in the global classpath, then use:

```
InputStream input = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("file.txt");
```

If it is placed in the webcontent, then just use:

```
InputStream input = new FileInputStream(servletContext.getRealPath("file.txt"));
```

The examples assumes that they're placed in the root. You can of course use relative path as opposed to the classpath root or webcontent root, e.g. `path/to/file.txt`. You can get the `ServletContext` in Struts by `ServletActionContext#getServletContext()`.

**Edit:** You edited your question with following:

> EDIT: Thank you guys for answer. For me worked this:
>
> ```
> String path=GetPointsOfInterestAction.class.getResource("../../../resources/visitor_attractions.txt")
> ```
>
> Could you please explain why

This is actually not the "right" way, but this is also doable. You only need to make sure that you **know** the *relative* path of the file as opposed to the actual path of the `GetPointsOfInterestAction` class. This class is of course placed in a different package, so you basically need to step a directory back (like you do in normal disk file systems: `cd ../` and so on). Again, this is not the most elegant way. You need to use one of the first two aforementioned ways, with the resource name `resources/visitor_attractions.txt`.

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://struts.apache.org/2.1.2/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/ServletActionContext.html)

`ServletActionContext.getServletContext()`

You seem to know what to do from there.

Comment: Yeap. The problem that if I try to read it in a constant it will return null. It seems a wrong design decision.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [Resource Bundle](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html).  I use them to look up properties files.  I believe that the directory just needs to be on the Classpath and the ResourceBundle will find it.

Answer (score 2):

If the file is on the classpath (which is not clear, but this would be a good idea), I'd suggest to use the utility class[`org.apache.struts2.util.ClassLoaderUtils`](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/util/ClassLoaderUtils.html). From its  java documentation:

> This class is extremely useful for loading resources and classes in a fault tolerant manner that works across different applications servers.

Pay a special attention to the [`ClassLoaderUtils.getResourceAsStream(String resourceName, Class callingClass)`](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/util/ClassLoaderUtils.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class)) static method which is a convenience method to load a resource as a stream. As documented, the algorithm used to find the resource is given in [`getRessource()`](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/util/ClassLoaderUtils.html#getResource(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class)):

> This method will try to load the
>   resource using the following methods
>   (in order):
>
> - From `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()`
> - From `ClassLoaderUtil.class.getClassLoader()`
> - From the `callingClass.getClassLoader()`